# Using an external App with laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I developed a website using laravel 5.2, but the problem an facing now is link it to an existing App like existing billing system, and livechat app.
Is it possible to just upload the folder to my laravel and call it directly?

Example: my-laravel-site.com/whmcs

where '/whmcs' is the directory of the already existing billing system.

If its possible how do I go about it?

Am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this simple step. Just drop the external application folder to the /public folder and call the url to the folder directly without any configuration or routing.

eg "public_html/billing" will become "domain.com/billing" without laravel interference.

Never thought it would be this simple.

Comment: ... Or you put it in a separate folder and configure your webserver accordingly to not mess different systems together.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to use existing apps within Laravel. But you need to follow the structure of Laravel. You need to add routes for the pages and let the Controller pick the right views. The app has to be placed in the /resources/views folder.

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-routing)

[Laravel Quick Start Video Series(devdojo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOU14L4xBis&list=PL_UnIDIwT95PiPV641VBnEwFAvswNZKuX)

Both are very useful and show you step for step how route to your app.